# directional derivative of a constant function

Tags: derivatives

I know that when a function is zero on a boundary, say $u=0$ on $\Gamma$, then $\nabla u = (\nabla u \cdot \nu)\nu$ where $\nu$ is the outward normal vector to $\Gamma$. My question is why is $\nabla u \cdot \tau$ ($\tau$ is the unit tangent vector) zero in this case? What if $u = const.$ on $\Gamma$. Is $\nabla u \cdot \tau$ also zero in this case?

Comment: we know that on the level surface, $\nabla u$ is parallel to the normal vector. It means that $\nabla u = c \nu$ for some $c$. Moreover, normal vector $\nu$ is perpendicular to the tangent vector, say $\tau$. Thus, $\nabla u \cdot \tau = c (\nu \cdot \tau ) = 0.$

Comment: So, in general, if $u = const.$, $\nabla u \cdot \tau$ is also zero, right? Thanks!